# UNION with dissimilar columns

Tags: sql-server

TABLE A

```
ID    Name    Age
1     John       22
```

TABLE B

```
ID   Name
5    Erik
```

I want result like

```
ID    Name    Age
1     John    22
5     Erik
```

When I am performing UNION giving error

"All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

How to get desired result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could supply a dummy column in lieu of the missing one that returns `NULL` as below.

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       Age
FROM   TABLE_A
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       NULL
FROM   TABLE_B
```